# Can select from but not insert into database mysql C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-insert

I have a connection to my db and I can retrieve data no problem but I'm unable to insert. The alert also isn't being displayed so I'm sure the query isn't being executed and it's just redirecting to the aspx page. I've tried many different solutions but I assume the problem is not where I'm looking. Here's the code, I hope someone can help.

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Childrens.Admin
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnViewStaff_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divAddStaff.Visible = false;
        staffGridView.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnAddNewStaff_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        staffGridView.Visible = false;
        divAddStaff.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnSubmitStaff_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword == txtCPassword)
        {
            using (SqlConnection addStaffConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    addStaffConn.Open();

                    string query = "INSERT INTO [Staff] (staff_fname,staff_sname,staff_email,staff_pass) VALUES ('" + txtFName + "','" + txtSName + "','" + txtEmail + "','" + txtPassword+"')"; //(@fname,@sname,@email,@pass)";
                    SqlDataAdapter staffAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    SqlCommand addStaffCommand = new SqlCommand(query, addStaffConn);

                    /*addStaffCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName);
                    addStaffCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", txtSName);
                    addStaffCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail);
                    addStaffCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword);*/
                    staffAdapter.InsertCommand = addStaffCommand;
                    staffAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    addStaffConn.Close();
                    Response.Write(String.Format("<script>alert('The entry was successful!');window.location='{0}';</script>", "URL=staff.aspx"));

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(String.Format("<script>alert('The entry was successful!');window.location='{0}';</script>", "URL=staff.aspx"));
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (addStaffConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        addStaffConn.Close();
                    }
                    addStaffConn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, 
   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 
/define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConn" connectionString="server=localhost;user 
id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=childrens" />
<add name="childrensConnectionString" 
connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=childrens;allowuservariables=True"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>

 </configuration>
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? I'm fairly sure you cannot use the (MS)SQL api for MySQL databases.

Comment: Unrelated Tips: the entire `finally` section is redundant and can be removed due to the `using ` block. `addStaffConn.Close();` is redundant for the same reason. SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are disposable so should be in `using` blocks. The catch block is reporting that it was successful. And although the AddWithValue is commented, I'd suggest reading [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: I didnt mention the Sql injection vulnerability, because I guessed you already knew, but I had second thoughts, and came back to mention it.

Comment: @Richardissimo I'm don't know much about sql security but the only vulnerability I can spot is that I have password set to password. is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @Uueerdo it's MySQL

Comment: Then thank goodness I came back. Google it yourself, but here is a good starter... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp  Your code actually has the parameters but it is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MySQL's [.Net Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), instead of a library intended for MS SQL Server. Also, data adapters tend to be used more for data tables and similar things; for your needs simply executing "command" objects should be sufficient.

The security vulnerabilities everyone is referring to is that your query (at best) breaks the second an "fname", "sname", etc... contains one or more apostrophes; you should look into parameterized queries to avoid such issues.

Edit: Also, `[` and `]` are field delimiters for Microsoft databases (MS SQL Server, and MS Access); the ` (on the ~ key) is used by MySQL.

Edit#2: Vulnerability example:

`INSERT INTO [Staff] (staff_fname,staff_sname,staff_email,staff_pass) VALUES ('" + txtFName + "','" + txtSName + "','" + txtEmail + "','" + txtPassword+"')"`

User puts in their first name as *`O','','','then'), ('they', 'can', 'add', 'multiple'), ('users','or','possibly','worse'), ('without','even','causing','an'), ('error`*

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out, I've tried it without field delimiters and I've had it as @fname etc. before but I've commented it out.

Comment: I've really just been trying a bunch of stuff. I'm using  MySQL .NET connector 6.9.11

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient`  is NOT MySQL's .Net Connector.

Comment: You appear to have connection strings for both mysql and ms sql in your configuration (and are not using the mysql one); if you need database portability System.Data.Odbc _might_ be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I'm obviously a noob and I appreciate the help. The code has a few more issues i'm working out but obviously the main issue was using the wrong connector.

Comment: @ShakiraRhianeSalazar You should mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the tick next to the answer, and upvote it because Uuerdo put extra helpful things in. Can I suggest that you also upvote my comments on improving your code, and pointing out the vulnerability as helpful.

Comment: @Richardissimo while your contributions have been undeniably helpful, they still haven't solved my issue. I can still select from the db and I'm unable to write to it. Rn it's running the code behind but when I try to display the data it's showing a server error :/ This is after a few corrections and additions of my own but at least it's some progress.

Comment: @ShakiraRhianeSalazar I'm sorry... when you said that was the main issue, I thought you meant it was solved. Did you get rid of the DataAdapter? Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if it gets hit? Also we cant see anything about the two variables in the `if` test - are they equal?